# Change enumeration from numbers to alphabet does not work if I manually edit space between items first

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I am trying to change enumeration from numbers to alphabet. i.e. instead of the list

```
1.
2.
3.
```

I want to have the list

```
(a)
(b)
(c)
```

For this I use the following commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2cm}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{0cm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\theoremstyle{remark} 
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\title{\textbf{Metric Spaces} \vspace{-0.5cm}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Basic Topology}
    \begin{definition} %\parskip0pt \parsep0pt
    A set $X$ together with a real-valued function $d$ is called a metric space if for all $x, y, z, \in X,$ the following properties are satisfied:

    \usepackage{enumitem}

    %%This command creates list.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item $ d(x,x)=0$
    \item $ d(x,y)>0 if x \neq y $
    \item $ d(x,y)=d(y,x) $
    \item $ d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y) $
    \end{enumerate}
```

If I do in the way above it works.

But, when I want to change vertical space between items, in the following way:

```
\let\oldenumerate\enumerate\renewcommand{\enumerate}{\oldenumerate\setlength{\itemsep}{3pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}
```

... it does not work.

So, to be clear this combination does not work:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2cm}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{0cm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\theoremstyle{remark} 
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\title{\textbf{Metric Spaces} \vspace{-0.5cm}}
\let\oldenumerate\enumerate\renewcommand{\enumerate}{\oldenumerate\setlength{\itemsep}{3pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Basic Topology}
    \begin{definition} %\parskip0pt \parsep0pt
    A set $X$ together with a real-valued function $d$ is called a metric space if for all $x, y, z, \in X,$ the following properties are satisfied:

    \usepackage{enumitem}

    %%This command creates list.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item $ d(x,x)=0$
    \item $ d(x,y)>0 if x \neq y $
    \item $ d(x,y)=d(y,x) $
    \item $ d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y) $
    \end{enumerate}
```

Could anyone help me what is the connection between these two commands and why the first nullifies the second one?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `enumitem` you should do this:

```
\setlist[enumerate,1]{itemsep=10pt}
```

to change some thing globally.

Your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\title{\textbf{Metric Spaces} \vspace{-0.5cm}}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{itemsep=10pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Basic Topology}
    \begin{definition} %\parskip0pt \parsep0pt
    A set $X$ together with a real-valued function $d$ is called a metric space if for all $x, y, z, \in X,$ the following properties are satisfied:

    %%This command creates list.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item $ d(x,x)=0$
    \item $ d(x,y)>0 if x \neq y $
    \item $ d(x,y)=d(y,x) $
    \item $ d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y) $
    \end{enumerate}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It would be more useful to post complete example that demonstrates the problem rather than fragments we can not use. But anyway you are using (but haven't said) `enumitem` which defines `\enumerate` to look for an optional argument, but then you define your command such that the command is always followed by `\setlength` so the optional argument is not seen. After your definition it is as if you had gone

```
\begin{enumerate}\setlength{\itemsep}{3pt}[label=(\alph*)]
```

Setting `\itemsep` inside the list is in any case the wrong place, since you are using `enumitem` you can set the list parameters within the optional argument.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question. I edited it (copied all my document) now. `\itemsep` is anyways turned off. I do not use it. If not defining new command how can I change vertical spaces between item globally in the whole document and at the same time use original `\enumerate`command that comes to `enumitem` package? Thank you for such a prompt answer. Appreciated!

Comment: @G.T. `texdoc enumitem` should show the documentation of the `enumitem` package. Section 5 Global Settings details how to change the defaults.